# Limited sequence of complex numbers

Tags: analysis

There is a version of Bolzano-weierstrass's theorem for bounded sequences of complex numbers? That is, it is true that if a sequence of complex numbers is limited so it has a convergent subsequence? If so, what would be the proof for this fact?

Comment: Yes, this is true.  One approach would be to consider the real and imaginary parts, which would also be bounded if the complex sequence is.  If you first choose a subsequence whose real parts are convergent, then you still have another step to take (choosing a subsequence of the subsequence).  That should be a sufficient hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bolzano-Weierstrass works for sequences $x_i$ contained in bounded sets $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with a proof that is very similar to the one-dimensional proof. It suffices to check it for boxes made out of Cartesian products of intervals (since I can fit any bounded set into one of these).

Then the proof goes: divide box $A$ into $2^n$ boxes with their sides parallel to the axes. Then one of these boxes has infinitely many members of the sequence in it. Call this box $A_1$. Choose the member of the sequence in $A_1$ with least index, call it $x'_1$. Remove $x'_1$ from the $x_i$, divide $A_1$ into $2^n$ boxes, choose the one with infinitely many members of the sequence in it, call it $A_2$, choose $x'_2$ as the least-indexed member of the sequence in $A_2$, repeat. It is clear that the $x'_i$ are Cauchy, because all the members after the $m$th iteration are within the box $A_m$, with sides $2^{-m}$ times smaller than those of $A$.

It's easy enough to patch the gaps in that to make it more formal, but that's the main idea.

Answer (score 1):

It can be extended to any $\mathbb{R}^n$ (And $\mathbb{C}$ is just $\mathbb{R}^2$) via:

"Finally, the general case can be easily reduced to the case of $n = 1$ as follows: given a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the sequence of first coordinates is a bounded real sequence, hence has a convergent subsequence. We can then extract a subsubsequence on which the second coordinates converge, and so on, until in the end we have passed from the original sequence to a subsequence $n$ times — which is still a subsequence of the original sequence — on which each coordinate sequence converges, hence the subsequence itself is convergent."

(via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Proof))